# /bin/sh: bad interpreter when running Cordova from bash script

Tags: bash, cordova, command-line

I'm writing a shell script to create a cordova project on the fly. It's called `build_android_app.sh` and it's simply:

```
function create_project(){
    cordova create testproject com.test testproject
}

echo "2/ Create Project"
create_project
```

At the command prompt, when I run:

```
cordova create testproject com.test testproject
```

everything works fine and the project is created. So then I try to run the script by executing:

```
bash build_android_app.sh
```

But I get the error:

```
 /c/Users/teamcity/AppData/Roaming/npm/cordova: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I am logged in as user "teamcity" and cordova is in the path at `/c/Users/teamcity/AppData/Roaming/npm/cordova`

The top of the cordova file starts with:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

I've spent many hours trying to get it working, including replacing cordova in the script with the absolute path to cordova. But I still get same error. Any ideas?

EDIT:

In `/c/Users/teamcity/AppData/Roaming/npm/` I ran:

```
cat -vet cordova
```

The first line printed out as:

```
#!/bin/sh$
```

So there is an extra `$` sign at the end. What is the solution to running this cordova file through a bash script?

EDIT
Actually, on my local windows machine, the sheep script works fine. This is even though I also see `#!/bin/sh$` when running `cat -vet cordova`.

The problem is on a windows server that I am remoting on to...

Comment: FYI, the `function` keyword isn't valid POSIX sh syntax. Just use `create_project() {`, with no leading `function`, for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Also, I **strongly** suggest looking for nonprintable characters in your script. If there's a DOS newline, for instance, it could be looking for `/bin/sh$'\r'`, not `/bin/sh`, and thus reporting a bad interpreter even if `/bin/sh` exists.

Comment: Try `cat -vet build_android_app.sh` and look for `^M` or anything similarly odd.

Comment: yes i see a lot of ^M$ when I run cat -vet build_android_app.sh

Comment: Skip the `bash` part, you don't need bash for this at all. Bash is big and bloaty, just set the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh`, make sure the script has the executable bit set (chmod +x scriptfile) and then run it with `./script`. It's possible bash is your default shell and it will run bash anyway, but give it a try.

Comment: again, this is working on my local windows machine, but on the server I get "'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: What error are you actually getting on the remote machine? The bad interpreter error or an error about `.` not being a command? Because that second error is a `cmd.exe` error which means you aren't in a `sh` or `bash` shell.

Comment: `/bin/sh$` is exactly what you'd _want_ `cat -vet` to show; it indicates that there aren't any unexpected characters there.

Comment: Since you're running on Windows: what Unix emulation environment are you using, and is it the same on your local machine and the remote server?

Comment: Sounds like your diagnostics are slightly off.  Something inside `build_android_app.sh` is clearly causing the error message.  If you run `bash -ex build_android_app.sh` you should be able to see exactly where the error is happening.

Comment: Try editing the `function create_project() {` line: You should choose between the syntax `function create_project {` and `create_project() {`.

Answer (score 0):

Error message says:

> /bin/sh: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Does `/bin/sh` exist?

A script:

```
#!/bin/foo-bar

echo hello
```

Running:

```
# ./foo 
-bash: ./foo: /bin/foo-bar: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I dont understand. It seems to be a problem with using bash to run the script but npm uses sh

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested, 'sounds like' an embedded control code - Without a 'non-edited' full version of the script to review (i.e. copy/paste to the web will most likely removed the offending code, if present...) this is kinda tough to resolve.  Things to try:

1) bash -n cordova # any errors?

2) zsh|ksh -n cordova # try another shell - any errors?

3) od -c cordova | more # look for any line with '\n \r' or other 'escaped' combos; 'normal lines' should end with '\n'

4) does 'cordova' call any other, external scripts?  try same things on those..

5) as noted by Igor, confirm that '/bin/sh' is present, i.e.

```
   ls -l /bin/sh ## is it there?
```

6) wild long shot (perhaps your terminal is not displaying 'everything'...)

```
cat cordova | tr -d '\r' > cordova.test
./cordova.test
```

7) replace '/bin/sh' with '/bin/bash'? ## may not be a good idea since there may be 'sh' and 'bash' variance for items in the script...

8) note that the She-bang line (#!/bin/sh | #/bin/bash | #!/bin/some_other_tool) must be the first (1st) line of the script, as in line number one

:)
Dale

Comment: thanks for all these suggesstions. For the moment, I've switched to doing this on a Mac, where it works fine. I will go through what you have suggested when we need to run it on Windows.

Comment: Hmm, I assumed you were working w/Linux (with typical user/shell environment); problem could be a Cygwin and/or other OS 'path issue' - which may need some tweaking...